# Convert computer PSU to 24VAC PSU?

Tags: power-supply

I have an old Dell 250watt DC power supply, and I quickly need a 24 **VOLT** AC ~60Hz Output PSU for a device that consumes 5 Watts. Is there any easy, safe way convert my PSU to so this? By the way, we get 120 VAC ~60Hz house-current here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Easy & safe? Nope. Computer PSUs are designed for DC output, not AC.

Try a local home-improvement or hardware store. Thermostat or doorbell transformers often put out 24 VAC, and will supply more than enough current for a 5-watt device.